# Uploading geoserver to onpenshift 503 error server unavailable

Tags: git, war, openshift, geoserver

Hi everybody i just create an app on openshift and upload the war file geoserver, but when i try to acces to the url http://geolopsa-geoserver1.rhcloud.com/ it's returns ERROR 503 Service Unavaible, the first time i run it's works perfectly. Then i had to logout from openshift and the app don't work again.

I use this tutorial to upload the files https://www.openshift.com/blogs/build-your-own-google-maps-and-more-with-geoserver-on-openshift#comment-39747

But don't use the Steven git repo, i download geoserver 2.5.1 last stable version of the server and folow the steps he gives.

Thanks.

Comment: Now I have the server running to enter geoserver use OpenShift page from the link in my app that is http://geolopsa-geoserver1.rhcloud.com clicking this ad tries to open http:// geolopsa-geoserver1.rhcloud.com/index.html but throws me the following error:
HTTP Status 500 - ServletContext resource [/ index.html] can not be resolved to absolute file path - web application archive not expanded?
To access geoserver I have to change http://geolopsa-geoserver1.rhcloud.com/index.html by web/ and everything works perfectly. How can i change the index for web.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably restart the application. If you're running on a free plan, the applications tend to go to 'sleep mode', or crash, without any signs in the openshift dashboard. Restarting geoserver takes 2 to 10 minutes, so be patient if you see the same error message after you've restarted.

Comment: Exactly what you say, when the app is not used in 72 hs it's goes to idle, so i need to reboot the services. What i did i use Monitor.us to make an http request every hour, so the services don't goes to idle. Thanks for the reply.